# Get all subsets of given size k from unordered_set?

Tags: c++, algorithm, subset

I have an `unordered_set<int> vertices` and have to generate all subsets of size exactly `k` for my clique program. All of solution (including all on SO) that I've seen work on arrays, not sets. Is there any algorithm like Python's `itertools.combinations` implemented in C++? If not, how should I go about it? Convert to array and use standard algorithm? I still have to use sets further in the program, so this would make my memory requirements twice as large.

Comment: Generation all subsets will take huge amount of time when number of elements become large (except for some special cases like choosing 0, 1, n-1, or n elements out of n), so I don't think doubing memory requirements will become serious problem unless you are developping programs for embedding or you have strict memory limit.

Comment: @MikeCAT so you suggest just to rewrite set to vector/array and then just generate combinations?

Comment: Yes, it should be a simple solution.

Comment: @MikeCAT thank you, maybe I've overthought this, please post an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generation all subsets will take huge amount of time when number of elements become large (except for some special cases like choosing 0, 1, n-1, or n elements out of n), so I don't think doubing memory requirements will become serious problem unless you have strict memory limit.

For that reason, I think you should just convert the set to an array and apply known algorithms.